# how to map design in iPhone objective C

Tags: iphone, integration, plist

i have a question that suppose i have 1 png which background is transparent and all the custom design are their suppose this: http://www.creativetechs.com/iq/tip_images/iPhoneElements-Yahoo.png

i want that i have add the png in my code and how could i get the cordinate and implement those images cordinate into UIImageView and when its run the it can grab those cordinate from the png and map the design.

I know its possible their is some software which can give the plist of those cordinate and then map it please any one guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question/answer explains how to create the subimage:
[Return a subimage from a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475881/return-a-subimage-from-a-uiimage)

I would suggest storing the coordinates in a plist (as you suggested) and using the above method to create each subimage from you sprite sheet.

(code from the above post)

```
CGRect fromRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); // or whatever rectangle

CGImageRef drawImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, fromRect);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawImage];
CGImageRelease(drawImage);
```

Comment: could you tell me which software is good to create plist for cordinate when i give the image & i don't use cocos i use UIKit so no sprite sheets... !!

Comment: For editing plist, you can Xcode or for something more lightweight, I use [Text Wrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Comment: This software ([zwoptexapp](http://zwoptexapp.com/)) appears to do what you are wanting. It will generate the plist file for you.