# Flip video around arbitrary axis

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have a video recorded by the user. I want the user to be able to define an arbitrary axis of rotation, and flip the video along that axis. I also want the final flipped video to crop to the original size.

[image]

I have used the `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)` to flip the video along the horizontal axis, but that's around the center point.

I'm already using an `AVMutableComposition` to do some compositing. Are there any `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` that would help?

_mike

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate where the user set the axis or how far the image is off set, flip the image and re-apply this offset in the opposite direction. Then you just need to get a subimage of an image.
Which you can do by doing this:

```
CGRect fromRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); // or whatever rectangle

CGImageRef drawImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, fromRect);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawImage];
CGImageRelease(drawImage);
```

[Code Reference Subimage of Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475881/return-a-subimage-from-a-uiimage)

Comment: I'm looking at doing this for a video, not just a single frame. I still like your approach about simple flip and then translate. I *think* there's a 'crop' mechanism for videos frames as well. Thanks for the info, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: oh, this might work, but if  you import QuartzCore and use the transition methods for the MPMoviewPlayerView.layer you might be able to achieve that, and put a mask over the video to make it seem like you cropped it