# get subImage from image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have following image,
[image]
 from that I need to use separate images like below.
[image]

 I don't know which kind of functionalities can be work here.

 I don't want to just crop that image from photoshop or anything like that. I know there is some way to achieve this. But don't know how to get sub-image.
I've searched somewhere long ago but now can't find the way.
could you please help me to get this.
I've already visited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4475883/4844767).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a subimage from a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475881/return-a-subimage-from-a-uiimage)

Comment: Already visited there, blog link is broken, in that code of answer, image was cropping, that I don't want

Comment: Didn't realise that. Vote for closing retracted.

Comment: What do you mean by *"get sub-image"* without cropping? Do you want to **mask** the image, to only show part of it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Swift 4

If I understood correctly you would want something like this:

[image] `[YOUR_FIRST_IMAGE]`

```
let image = UIImage(named: "[YOUR_FIRST_IMAGE]")
let fromRect = CGRect(x:[OFFSET_HERE], y:0,width:[WIDTH_OF_EACH_ICON],height:[HEIGHT_OF_EACH_ICON])
let croppedImageFromRect = image?.cgImage!.cropping(to: fromRect)
let dottedCircleGreenImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedImageFromRect!)

imageView.image = dottedCircleGreenImage
```

To select a different sub image from this collection (`[YOUR_FIRST_IMAGE]`) you have to offset the `x` (in the `CGRect`) with the width of each icon multiplied by the position of image you want minus 1.

For example to select the fifth one: [image]. Get the width of a single icon than multiply it by 5.

**Notes**:

`imageView` in the above example is some outlet or form of reference to a UIImageView in a view.

force unwrapping variables is not a good practise, this is just per example.

Comment: yes, got that idea. but as I don't want to crop image...
Still it's a good if no any other way

Comment: Other then imitating a sliding image which clips on bounds in it's superview (like how CSS does it), there are no other options (or my knowledge isn't sufficient). Place a UIImageView inside another view, have this superview clip to bounds and the imageView not. Then use the same logic as in the answer to decide how far to offset the imageView in the super view. If you'd like I can type up an example. Though it is not a recommended if you ask me, it is a hacky approach.